# how to align text in android when using html code

Tags: android

i create a imageview and textview in android with the help of html code so my question is how to align text and when i click Read more then it will open new pase so.. here is my full source code.can anyone help me please.thanks in advance

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String htmlText = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>We understand that different client have different needs and requirements therefore special effort might be required to fulfill these requirements. Our custom software development services are aimed to fulfill......Read More &nbsp;</p>" +

            "<blockquote>Example from <a href=\"www.javatechig.com\">" +
            "Javatechig.com<a></blockquote></body>";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          TextView htmlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_text);
          htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));

}
}
```

**My Layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".MainActivity" 
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/html_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align text below image remove following lines from text view in your layout

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
```

And add following line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
```

**With Webview**

Replace your layout with following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And use following code in your **activity**

```
private final String htmlText = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>We understand that different client have different needs and requirements therefore special effort might be required to fulfill these requirements. Our custom software development services are aimed to fulfill......Read More &nbsp;</p>" +

            "<blockquote>Example from <a href=\"http://www.javatechig.com\">" +
            "Javatechig.com<a></blockquote></body>";

    private WebView m_webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         m_webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         m_webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                 if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.javatechig.com/")) {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     return true;
                 }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
         });
         m_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlText, "text/html", HTTP.UTF_8, null);
    }
```

Comment: sorry not getting you can you please provide provide more detail?

Comment: for example i have a text like  <how r u......Read more> so when i click Read more then it will be open new android layout activity.... sir can u guide me please

Comment: You can do this but for that you have to use webview.

Comment: can u provide me any example because i m new in android

Comment: yaaa but i have only 10 reputation that's why i m unable to chat with any one because i m very new here...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:gravity="center"` in your xml for your TextView if you want to align your text at the center of it.

To open your page try : `htmlTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: i wana align text below image in side

Comment: Well, your xml looks good. Where is your text located at this time ?